# Importing raw mysql files

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Please do not mark this as a duplicate, I've tried all the other threads and they have not helped me.
So basically, I installed MariaDB (was installing dependencies for Pterodactyl) which for some reason deleted MySQL. I went to /var/lib and copied the mysql folder to a secure location. I do not have any .sql backup or dump. Is there any way I can make use of that backup? To add, I have now shifted to MariaDB.

Comment: You can avoid "for some reason" surprises by carefully reading your output. The system clearly tells you exactly what it is going to do when it gives you a chance to approve/reject the changes. Your question seems answered by https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-migrate-from-mysql-to-mariadb-on-linux-in-five-steps/. That blog post was very easy to find, so I'm not sure why you were trying "all the other threads."

Comment: @user535733 Since that seems to be the answer, would you be willing to post an answer about it?